# Trying to find correct way to infinitely loop in my code-behind file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm attempting to rotate through a series of numbered pictures sequentially in a C# code-behind section of a Master Content Page for a project I'm working with. I'm trying to start at 1, move to 5, and then start the process again. This is what I have so far. It doesn't work because you need additional conditions in the `if` section.

```
int i = 1;
restart:
while (i < 6)
{
   Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/" + i.ToString() + ".png";
   i++;
   if (i == 5)
   {
      restart;
   }
}
```

EDIT: 
After trying to prepend "GOTO" to the label, I can't get the page to load.  Here is the rest of the file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


namespace Clark
{
    public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                SetImageURL(); // To ensure image loads on page load
            }
        }

        protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetImageURL(); // Refactored from previous logic
        }

        private void SetImageURL()
        {
            // The random function will choose between 1&5 which
            // correspond to images 1 through 5
            //Random _rand = new Random();
            //int i = _rand.Next(1, 5);
            //Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/" + i.ToString() + ".png";
            int i = 1;
            restart:
            while (i < 6)
            {

                Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/" + i.ToString() + ".png";
                i++;
                if (i == 5)
                {
                    restart;
                }
            }

            /*
            while (true)
            {
                int i = 1;
                do
                {
                    Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/" + i.ToString() + ".png";
                    i++;
                } while (i < 6);
            } */



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What additional conditions do you need?

Comment: What are you doing with the :Labels this is a phenomenal symbol but rarely used for good reason.

Comment: Also, admittedly, I'm not really sure why this *doesn't* work. The above comment is definitely right that you shouldn't be using labels, because they're just dreadful to read and use, but why doesn't this work? I know you say you need additional conditions, but there should be no reason that such conditions couldn't be applied to the code you already have.

Comment: Visual Basic says "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement."

Comment: Oh, yes, you need to prepend "GoTo" there. I thought that was a typo, sorry. `GoTo restart` should be that line. Although again, avoid use of those.

Comment: Ok -- so that kept the code behind error free, but I've also refactored the logic to a function for page load and it doesn't work when I attempt tor run the project.

Comment: In what way does it not work? Compiler error? Runtime? Unexpected results?

Comment: Runtime -- I've included the rest of the code behind file above.

Comment: At first, I did it randomly -- but now I'm trying to get it to work sequentially.

Comment: What error are you getting? What does it say?

Comment: It presently doesn't say anything -- It just hangs and continually tries to load the page.

Comment: This code cannot work. Why reinvent the wheel when you can grab a free carousel anywhere?

Comment: @IrishChieftain -- I'm not actively trying to reinvent anything; I'm just trying to get it to work.

Comment: Okay, well then you're caught in an infinite loop. What are you trying to accomplish? Like, big picture?

Comment: When the .aspx page this is attached to is loaded, I would like for it to load a picture in a content section and go through the pictures sequentially from 1 to 5 (that's how they're named 1.png etc).  If you look at the additional code I posted above, you'll see how I was doing it before commented out.  That way was random, however, I want it to be sequential.

Comment: It worked find randomly -- but I want to avoid that if possible.

Comment: I think you should learn how the web works first. Especially ASP.NET. Each time the page is invoked, it goes through its cycle, then generates some HTML and sends it to the browser. Once the HTML is sent, the page is destroyed. There is no continuous connection between the codebehind and the browser. Changing the ImageUrl does nothing until the page finally returns HTML to the browser, and in that case, only the final ImageUrl actually matters!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use nested loops.

```
do
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++;
    {
        Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/" + i.ToString() + ".png";
    }
}
while (/* additional conditions */)
```

I chose the `do`/`while` architecture because it maps best to what you already have, but just a plain-ol' `while` would do the trick too.

Although that all said, remember that unless this is just an example, this is a pretty silly thing to do. Your `ImageUrl` won't be read while you're in this loop, so you could just calculate out what the result will actually be and not have to waste the time and resources to run what could turn into an infinite loop like this.

**Edit:**

The question has evolved.

Instead of using loops, store an Application variable:

```
object imageIndexObj = Application["imageIndex"];
int imageIndex;
if(imageIndexObj == null)
    imageIndex = 1;
else
    imageIndex = (int)imageIndexObj;

Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/" + (imageIndex % 5) + ".png";

Application["imageIndex"] = imageIndex + 1;
```

There are some implications here, particularly when dealing with multiple-server farms. But this should suffice for your case. If you hit a user-load wherein multiple servers are required, then using a workflow like this will likely become irrelevant, since the result will be more random anyway.

You could also use `Session` in place of `Application` here, if you want the five images to cycle for each session, rather than for each request. That's your call. The code's the same other than that, though.

Comment: That did it.  Thank you ever so much -- I tried to upvote you but I need 15 reputation :/    In any case, many thanks!

Comment: Glad we could figure it out! I wish I knew why I got downvoted for this, but such is such.